# What is the method used to find the singular points of an ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-forms

Suppose you have an ODE, say
$$
x^{2} (x+1) y'' +  2y' + xy = 0
$$
How would you find the singular points of this?

I've looked online for an explanation of the method used to do this, but have not found any that I understand very well. Can anyone outline the method used to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-writing
$$y''+\frac{2}{x^{2}(x+1)}y'+\frac{1}{x(x+1)}y$$
You see that the singular points are $x=0, -1$.
See http://www.math.washington.edu/~toro/Courses/99-00/135/regular.pdf
For a further discussion

**Further Edit**
Write the most general ODE
$$N(x)y''+P(x)y'+ Q(x) = 0$$
in *standard form*
$$y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$$

Let $x_{0}$ be a singular point, and, multiply by $(x-x_{0})^{2}/N(x)$ one can write
$$(x-x_{0})^{2}y''+(x-x_{0})u(x)y'+v(x)y=0$$ where
\begin{align}
u(x) &= \frac{(x-x_{0})P(x)}{N(x)}\\
v(x) &= \frac{(x-x_{0})^{2}Q(x)}{N(x)} 
\end{align}
$x_{0}$ is then *regular* if $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ have no singularity at $x_{0}$; otherwise it is an *irregular* point.

I have regurgitated a lot of the detail in the link I have posted, see the theory on page 1.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a method for finding out which of these is regular and irregular?

Comment: @user2910074 Yes there is, see edit for details. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Cusp points when $ y''$ goes to infinity. Here at $ x=0,-1$there would be curve reversal/sudden direction change etc.